# C program won't compile despite using proper specifier?

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

For reasons that I don't understand at the moment, this code will not compile despite having everything it needs in order to do the task.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>


double resistance;
double voltage;
double current;
double wattage;
int main()
{

    printf("type in resistance\n");
    scanf("%f",resistance);
    printf("type in current");
    scanf("%f",current);
    //voltage = resistance*resistance*current;
    printf("%f Volts",resistance*resistance*current);

    //  return voltage;
}
```

The thing I don't understand is why won't it compile?  I keep getting "*wrong specifier*" message when compiling. I tried both `%lf` and `%f` but neither of them works.

Comment: Look closer at the second parameter to `scanf`.

Comment: E.g. GCC gives you proper information: `x.c:13:7: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]`

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, they both look the same to me.   I take it you're referring to scanf("%f",current);

Comment: BTW: `voltage = resistance*resistance*current` is wrong.  Should be `voltage = resistance*current`

Answer (score 4):

You want to assign a floating value to your double vars by using scanf. The arguments need to be pointer :

```
int main() {

    printf("\ntype in resistance\n");
    scanf("%lf",&resistance);
    printf("\ntype in current");
    scanf("%lf",&current);
    //voltage = resistance*resistance*current;
    printf("\n%f Volts",resistance*resistance*current);
    // return voltage; 
}
```

Comment: for some reason I keep getting 0 as an answer?  is it using * as a pointer and not for multiplication?

Comment: `double resistance; scanf("%lf",&resistance);` --> Add `l`.

Comment: @obito94: print out the values of `resistance` and `current` after you enter them.  And as I pointed out below, you should use `%lf` to read into `double` variables.

Comment: i get the value for resistance now but current never displays and the answer in volts for some reason always = resistance

Answer (score 4):

Change the lines

```
scanf("%f",resistance);
scanf("%f",current);
```

to

```
scanf("%lf", &resistance);
scanf("%lf", &current);
```

The `%f` conversion specifier expects the corresponding argument to have type `float *`, but both expressions `resistance` and `current` have type `double`.  The expressions `&resistance` and `&current` have type `double *`, so you need to use the `%lf` conversion specifier (which expects arguments of type `double *`).

Comment: Related question: is there no `<inttypes.h>` for floats?

Comment: @Kay: There is a `<float.h>`, but it doesn't provide any specific-width types or formatting macros the way `<inttypes.h>` does.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the printf, it is the scanf:

```
scanf("%f", resistance);
```

This should be:

```
scanf("%lf", &resistance);
```

`%lf` because it is a double, `%f` is for floats. And `&resistance` because `scanf` is expecting a pointer to whatever, so it could write there. When you write `%f`, `printf` expects just a float, `scanf` a pointer to float. `%lf` and it's `double`/`double*`.

Comment: `"%lf"` because it is a `double *`, `"%f"` is for `floats *`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the standard of C99, there is no exclusive format specifier for float. Whether you use a float or double, it doesn't count. What matters is that when you use a float variable printf automatically promotes it to a double and displays it. So %f indicates a double or a floating-point value and %Lf is used for a long double value.

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

```
int main() {

   printf("Type in Resistance: ");
   scanf("%lf", &resistance);
   printf("Type in Current: ");
   scanf("%lf", &current);
   printf("%f Volts",resistance*resistance*current);
}
```

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: This answer concerns the format specifier with `printf()` which is not OP's problem.  OP's problem is the incorrect format specifier with `scanf()`.  Using  `"%f"` or `"%lf"` and their _matching_ pointer type is critical.